# split text string by array of properties

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a block of text which is supposed to have different types of formatting. The text and the formatting tags are stored in a string and an array respectively. I want to create a data structure that will hold the 2 together. Here is actual working data:

#### Formatted text:

this text is **bold** while this is *italic* and this is **bold** too.

#### Text string:

`this text is bold while this is italic and this is bold too.`

#### Format tags array:

```json
{
  "bold":[
    [13,16],
    [51,54]
  ],
  "italic":[
    [32,37]
  ]
}
```

Note that the format tags array contains the **start** and **end** of different types of formatted text.

Now the question is: How could I merge these 2 types of information to create one good object holding the two. A generic format that can be converted into HTML and Markdown would be appreciated. I was thinking about:

```json
[
  {text:"this text is ", tags: []}.
  {text: "bold", tags: ["bold"]},
  {text: "while this is ", tags: []},
  {text: "italic", tags: ["italic"]},
  {text: " and this is ", tags: []},
  {text: "bold", tags: ["bold"]},
]
```

Also note that it is possible for one text slice to have multiple tags.

Comment: Honestly??? Why not do `this text is **bold** while this is *italic* and this is **bold** too.` instead? Markdown is by far the shortest and simplest way to encode your string.

Comment: I need to store the text in a format which can be easily be displayed back to a GTK TextView. Storing the text in Markdown could mean parsing it to display it again.

Comment: Although I added an answer, because I found this an interesting challenge, I think Carsten is right.  Parsing Markdown when needed would be simple enough, and fast enough for most purposes.  Have you tried it to decide that it's not worthwhile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that handles simple overlapping tags.

It's fairly dense, and there's a partial explanation below.

```js
const restructure = (text, tags) =>
  Object .entries (
    Object .entries (tags) .reduce ((a, [tag, blocks]) => blocks .reduce ((a, [start, end]) => ({
      ... a,
      [start]: {... ({...a [start] || {open: [], close: []}}), open: [... ((a [start] || {}).open || []), tag]},
      [end + 1]: {... ({...a [end + 1] || {open: [], close: []}}), close: [... ((a [end + 1] || {}).close || []), tag]}
    }), a), {0: {close: [], open: []}, [text.length - 1]: {close: [], open: []}})
  ) .map (([k, v]) => [Number (k), v]) .sort  (([a], [b]) => a - b) 
    .reduce (
      (a, y, i, arr, x = arr [i - 1], 
        tags = i == 0 ? [] : [... new Set(a .open .filter (tag => ! x [1] .close .includes (tag)) .concat (x [1] .open || []))]
      ) => i == 0 ? a : {open: tags, blocks: a .blocks .concat ({text: text .slice (x [0], y [0]), tags})}, 
      {open: [], blocks: []}
    )
    .blocks

const testCases = [
  {
    text: "this text is bold while this is italic and this is bold too.", 
    tags: {bold: [[13, 16], [51, 54]], italic: [[32, 37]]}
  }, {
    text: "this text is bold while this is italic and this is bold too.", 
    tags: {bold: [[13, 16], [51, 54]], red: [[29, 33]], italic: [[32, 37]]}
  }, {
    text: "There's bold and italic then just italic and then there's neither.", 
    tags: {bold: [[8, 11]], italic: [[8, 49]]}
  }
]

testCases .forEach (({text, tags}) => {
  console .log (`Text: `, text)
  console .log (`Tags: `, tags)
  console .log (`Result: `, restructure (text, tags))
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start by calling `Object .entries (tags)` and then doing a `reduce` on the results.  If we start with the text

```js
"this text is bold while this is italic and this is bold too."
```

and the tags

```js
{"bold":[[13,16],[51,54]],"italic":[[32,37]]}
```

this will yield

```js
{
  "0": {close: [], open: []},
  "13": {close: [], open: ["bold"]},
  "17": {close: ["bold"], open: []},
  "32": {close: [], open: ["italic"]},
  "38": {close: ["italic"], open: []},
  "51": {close: [], open: ["bold"]},
  "55": {close: ["bold"], open: []},
  "59": {close: [], open: []}
}
```

Note that we shifted the end indices up by one, as the norm in JS is for the left index to be inclusive and the right one to be exclusive.  `"close"` and `"open"` here are meant to indicate *events* we will process, and not current states.

We then wrap that up with another `Object .entries` and follow it with `map` and `sort` calls.  The `map` is not actually necessary, and I would probably remove it in the end, but it feels cleaner than sorting numeric strings through subtraction.

That now turns this into an ordered list of event groups:

```js
[
  [0, {"close": [], "open": []}],
  [13, {"close": [], "open": ["bold"]}],
  [17, {"close": ["bold"], "open": []}],
  [32, {"close": [], "open": ["italic"]}], 
  [38, {"close": ["italic"], "open": []}], 
  [51, {"close": [], "open": ["bold"]}],
  [55, {"close": ["bold"], "open": []}],
  [59, {"close": [], "open": []}]
]
```

Note that although this example only has single values tied with any index, a more complex scenario could have several opens and several closes in one place.

We do a second `reduce` on these, starting with an initial accumulator of `{open: [], blocks: []}`, keeping track of the collection of tags that are open, and appending to `blocks` on each event, leading to:

```js
{
  blocks: [
    {tags: [],         text: "this text is "}, 
    {tags: ["bold"],   text: "bold"}, 
    {tags: [],         text: " while this is "}, 
    {tags: ["italic"], text: "italic"}, 
    {tags: [],         text: " and this is "}, 
    {tags: ["bold"],   text: "bold"}, 
    {tag": [],         text: " too"}
  ], 
  open: []
}
```

This bit

```js
[... new Set(a .open .filter (tag => ! x [1] .close .includes (tag)) .concat (x [1] .open || []))]
```

first removes from the accumulator's `open` array all tags that are in the current `close` list, then adds all the ones in the current `open` list, and uses `[...new Set (/* ... */)]` to reduce to a list of unique values.

And then finally we simply return the `blocks` property of this accumulator object.

Syntactically, I know, it's still dense.  If I find time soon, I will try to write a more imperative -- and probably much longer -- version of this.

Note that this will handle all sorts of overlap.  But it will not handle nested versions of the same tag.  If you have `{bold: [[12, 20], [15, 30]]}` it will likely close off all bold at the end of the first one (that is, at `20`, not `30`.)  This is fixable using queues instead of simple arrays of opened tags, but is quite a bit more work, I would think.

### Update

I said I'd try to write a more imperative version of this code.  Here it is:

```js
const restructure = (text, tags) => {
  const entries = Object .entries (tags)
  const events = {
    0: {close: [], open: []}, 
    [text.length - 1]: {close: [], open: []}
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < entries .length; i ++) {
    const [tag, blocks] = entries [i]
    for (let j = 0; j < blocks .length; j ++) {
      const [start, end] = blocks [j]
        events [start] = events [start] || {open: [], close: []}
        events [start] .open .push (tag)
        events [end + 1] = events [end + 1] || {open: [], close: []}
        events [end + 1] .close .push (tag)
    }
  }

  const eventEntries = Object .entries (events) 
  const sortedEventEntries = eventEntries .sort  (([a], [b]) => a - b) 
  
  let openTags = []
  const textBlocks = []
  
  for  (let i = 1; i < sortedEventEntries .length; i++) {
    const [start, {open, close}] = sortedEventEntries [i - 1]
    const [end] = sortedEventEntries [i]
    const tags = openTags .filter (tag => close .includes (tag)) 
    const allTags = tags .concat (open || [])
    openTags = [... new Set (allTags)]
    textBlocks .push ({
      text: text .slice (start, end), 
      tags: openTags
    })
  }

  return textBlocks
}
```

I believe it has the same behavior.  The first version was far too dense.  This one is much less dense, but I don't like the reliance on so many local variables, especially not the mutable ones.  And I absolutely detest `for` loops.  I won't spend the time now, but I think the best version would be one that uses the same approach as the denser one above but uses a few helper functions to manage the density and complexity.

Comment: Updated to demonstrate a less dense, imperative version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```js
/*
Groups range tags
@param {Object} tagsMap
@returns {Object} rangeTagsMap
*/
const _groupRangeTags = tagsMap => 
  Object.entries(tagsMap).reduce((map, [tag, ranges]) => {
    ranges.forEach(range => map[range] = [...(map[range] ?? []), tag]);   
    return map;
  }, {});
  
/*
Lists sorted range objects with tags
@param {Object} rangeTagsMap
@returns {Array} rangeTagsList
*/
const _listRangesWithTags = rangeTagsMap =>
  Object.entries(rangeTagsMap)
    .map(([range, tags]) => {
      const [start, end] = range.split(',');
      return { start: +start, end: +end, tags };
    })
    .sort(({ start: a }, { start: b }) => a - b);

/*
Returns range objects with tags including the ones without tags
@param {Array} rangeTagsList
@param {String} str
@returns {Array} strRangeTagsList
*/
const _fillRangesWithoutTags = (rangeTagsList, str) => {
  const strRangeTagsList = [];
  if(rangeTagsList.length === 0) {
    strRangeTagsList.push({ start: 0, end: str.length, tags: [] });
  } 
  for (i = 0; i < rangeTagsList.length; i++) {
    const current = rangeTagsList[i], next = rangeTagsList[i+1];
    strRangeTagsList.push(current);
    if(i === 0 && current.start !== 0) {
      strRangeTagsList.unshift({ start: 0, end: current.start-1, tags: [] });
    }
    if (next && current.end != next.start) {
      strRangeTagsList.push({ start: current.end+1, end: next.start-1, tags: [] });
    }
    if(i === rangeTagsList.length-1 && current.end !== str.length-1) {
      strRangeTagsList.push({ start: current.end+1, end: str.length, tags: [] });
    }
  }
  return strRangeTagsList;
}

/*
Returns string range objects with text and tags
@param {Array} strRangeTagsList
@param {String} str
@returns {Array} strRanges
*/
const _getTextRanges = (strRangeTagsList, str) => strRangeTagsList.map(({ start, end, tags }) => ({ 
  text: str.substring(start, end+1), tags 
}));

/*
@param {String} str
@param {Object} tagsMap
@returns {Array} strRanges
*/
const _getRanges = (str, tagsMap = {}) => {
  const rangeTagsMap = _groupRangeTags(tagsMap);
  const rangeTagsList = _listRangesWithTags(rangeTagsMap);
  const strRangeTagsList = _fillRangesWithoutTags(rangeTagsList, str);
  return _getTextRanges(strRangeTagsList, str);
}
  
console.log( _getRanges('this text is bold while this is italic and this is bold too.', { bold: [ [13,16], [51,54] ], italic: [ [32,37] ] }) );
console.log( _getRanges('this is bold while this is both bold and italic.', { bold: [[8,11],[32,46]], italic: [[32,46]] }) );
```

Comment: it doesnt work when there one text slice has 2 or more tags

Comment: @vixalien I tested this case, what are you trying exactly?

Comment: text: `this is bold while this is both bold and italic.` tags: `{"bold":[[8,11],[32,46]],"italic":[[32,46]]}`

Comment: @vixalien I added this example to test, isn't the above the expected output?

Comment: Let me know if you face other edge cases, it would be nice to solidify this approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242498/discussion-between-vixalien-and-majed-badawi).

Comment: i found a bug. go to discussion for more details

Comment: i seem stuck, ill ask another question